# How to run emulator64-arm in a Docker container?

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, arm, qemu

I tried to run emulator64-arm in a Docker container but it reported:

```
$ emulator64-arm -avd t2 -no-window -no-accel -gpu off
qemu: could not open disk image /home/testuser/.android/avd/t2.avd/sdcard.img: Interrupted system cal
```

I think qemu-aarch64 should be a pure software emulator without any fancy things involved but I was wrong.
I also tried to start the container with `--privileged` but still no luck.

In my case we need to run some smoke tests for our Android APK, speed doesn't really matter but Android-X86 is not an option.

Comment: Can be everything: permissions? Did you create the emulator inside the container or you bind the volume? Does the sdcard.img exists? Can you please share the Docker file?

Comment: @spacifici I really don't have a Dockerfile, I installed all dependencies manually, android-sdk, environment variables etc. After the same procedure it worked outside of the container but not inside. I'm just wondering what does this "Interrupted system call" mean, it shouldn't appear even if the img didn't exist, and yes, sdcard.img is there.

Comment: I have a sandbox playground where I run emulator without hardware acceleration. You can check it here https://github.com/plastiv/peta-androidsdk/blob/master/android-28/version-check.sh#L18 to see if anything obvious is different with your setup.

Comment: @spacifici sorry for the late response, I tried your Docker container but it didn't work. The APK I'll test is for ARM instead of X86, I used your project as the base, added ARM system image, but the emulator still cannot start and reported the same error. I guess there is something weird in qemu-arm which is incompatible with Docker.

Comment: There is a bug/issue open which seems to prevent emulator-arm64 to boot emulator on linux host. Star it for updates. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127531118

Comment: Please provide "docker info" output, verbose output and Dockerfile (set of all used commands for installation) - that will help to replicate your ssue.

Comment: I just found a solution today and I still have no idea what happened. AVD created under Linux will also create a "qcow2" file for each image, but not on any other OS, with these qcow2 files the emulator can successfully boot. I was using an AVD created under Mac and it cannot be used.

Comment: @Windoze great that it worked. Please, consider self-answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

**This is not about the root cause but a workaround.**

AVD created under Linux will also create "qcow2" files for each image, with these qcow2 files, emulator can successfully start.

But these qcow2 files are not created under any other platforms, I was using an AVD created under Mac and got the error, then I recreated AVD under Linux and the error was gone.